# Loop through an Array - How do I fix Run-Time Error 9?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through an array so that a cell value equals an element of that array.  I am getting a run-time error 9 on the line of the code that starts ".Range("I3")..." I think I have laid everything out properly so I can't understand why I am getting this error. Does anyone know? Thanks!

```
Dim MyArray(4 To 14979, 10 To 10) As String
Dim wsBalance As Worksheet

Set wsBalance = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Balance")



    With wsBalance

    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)

        .Range("I3") = MyArray(i, 1)

        Next i

    End With
```

Comment: You should look at debugging and add watch on the array, use a breakpoint and you would immidiatly see that your array is wrongly declared. Google "basic debugging in vba" and you will find lots of examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared the array with a wrong value ..
This should work.

```
Dim MyArray(4 To 14979, 1 To 10) As String
```

For looping and editing the values in cells here a little exampe:

```
 With wsBalance     
     For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)         
         MyArray(i, 1) = "MyValue " & i         
         .Cells(i, 3) = MyArray(i, 1)         
     Next i     
 End With
```

Comment: Thanks that got it to run. But when I run it my value in I3 is blank. I want to assign I3 based on the value(s) in my array?

Comment: Then you need to initialize the array with the values you want, default is empty. I think you want to loop over some more cells, a little example
`code     
With wsBalance
    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        MyArray(i, 1) = "MyValue " & i
        .Cells(i, 3) = MyArray(i, 1)
        Next i
    End With
`

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it. I was hoping it wouldn't take so long to loop through my array. Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: @R.Karl: Please don't dump a bunch of code or extended explanations in comments. It's obviously quite difficult to read. Just edit it into your answer, click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25445341/edit) link.

Comment: Excel repaints the whole sheet with every write action. So the brute way is deactivating the screen updating (with Application.ScreenUpdating = false). But you have to reactivate it at the end of the loop or you won't be able to use Excel til restart. So you need to implement some error handling, wich is reactivating the screenupdating in case of an error (like a cell is locked or so).